# Two definitions of spin structure

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, principal-bundles

There is a say *standard* definition of spin structure for an oriented manifold $M$: it is a principial $spin(n)$ bundle $Spin(M)$ together with the equivariant map $\eta:Spin(M) \to SO(M)$ where $SO(M)$ is orthonormal frame bundle (of oriented frames) and equivariance is understood via the concrete map $\rho: spin(n) \to SO(n)$ being $2:1$ covering map. However I met also the following definition:
*Spin structure on oriented $M$ is a principial $spin(n)$ bundle $P$ together with an explicit isomorphism $P \times_{\rho} \mathbb{R}^n \cong TM$ (left hand side is associated bundle).*

> I would like to understand how this definition implies the standard one.

Here are some my attempts:
1. There is always the isomorphism $O(M) \times_{id} \mathbb{R}^n \cong TM$ where $O(M)$ is orthonormal frame bundle. Once $M$ is oriented we can replace $O(M)$ by $SO(M)$.
2. Therefore our assumption gives us isomorphism $P \times_{\rho} \mathbb{R}^n \cong SO(M) \times_{id} \mathbb{R}^n$ so we get that the two associated bundles are isomorphic. Does it follows from this that we have an equivariant map $\eta:P \to SO(M)$? It seems to me that it should be true or at least well known (since this is general question, what one can say about the existence of maps between principial bundles, having some assumptions for the existence of isomorphism between the associated vector bundles).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your attempts go in the right direction, but you are missing one step: If you have a principal $SO(n)$-bundle $Q\to M$ such that $Q\times_{SO(n)}\mathbb R^n\cong TM$ (as oriented bundles endowed with a metric), then $Q\cong SO(M)$. This can be seen directly, since to a point $y\in Q$ over $x\in M$, you can associate a linear isomorphism $\mathbb R^n\to T_xM$ by mapping $v\in\mathbb R^n$ to the class of $(y,v)$ in the associated bundle. Compatibility with the metric and the orientation shows that this map is orthogonal and orientation preserving.

Now given a principal $Spin(n)$-bundle $P\to M$, you can always quotient by $\mathbb Z_2$ to get a principal $SO(n)$-bundle $Q=P/{\mathbb Z_2}\to M$. By definition of the action of $Spin(n)$ on $\mathbb R^n$, you see that $P\times_{Spin(n)}\mathbb R^n\cong Q\times_{SO(n)}\mathbb R^n$. Hence form the above argument you get an isomorphism $Q\to SO(M)$ and composing this with the canonical projection $P\to Q$, you see that $P$ defines a Spin-sturcture.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just to be sure if I understood things correctly: the map $y \mapsto (v \mapsto [(y,v)])$ acts from the principial bundle $Q$: its value on $y$ is an element in $SO(T_xM)$ where we use the identification of $T_xM$ with $(Q \times_{SO(n)} R^n)_x$. I don't see immediately why this map should be surjective: however please point me whether I think correctly. Once we have this map we can consider the map which sends $y$ to the $n$-tuple $([(y,e_1),...,[(y,e_n)])$ where $(e_k)_k$ is a standard basis of $R^n$. From the arguments discussed it follows that this $n$-tuple ...

Comment: ... is in fact an element in $SO(M)_x$ (the orthonormal frame bundle) and one shows that this map is equivariant, i.e. it is a morphism of prinicpial $SO(n)$-bundles. Once we have this, from the general theory it follows that any such morphism is automatically isomorphism (and in particular we don;t need the fact that the map which you have described is surjective)? And the second question: could you give some explanation why we can consider $Q:=P/ \mathbb{Z}_2$ and we have a map $P \to Q$?On each fiber this is obvious however is it obvious that we can do this globally?

Comment: The group $\mathbb Z_2$ is the kernel of the projection $Spin(n)\to SO(n)$, so it is a normal subgroup of $Spin(n)$, which thus acts freely on the total space of any $Spin(n)$-principal bundle via the principal right action. It is elementary that $Q:=P/\mathbb Z_2$ is a smooth manifold, the obvious projection $P\to Q$ is a 2-fold covering, and the obvious projection $Q\to M$ is a principal bundle with structure group $Spin(n)/\mathbb Z_2\cong SO(n)$. The restriction of the $Spin(n)$-action to $\mathbb Z_2$ is trivial, which implies isomorphism of the associated bundles ...

Comment: $P\times_{Spin(n)}\mathbb R^n$ and $Q\times_{SO(n)}\mathbb R^n$. The surjectivity in your first question follows since both bundles have fiber $SO(n)$ and the map is equivariant for the principal right action. (This is basically the fact from "general theory" that you refer to.) Things are much easier if you view the fiber $SO(M)_x$ as orientation preserving orthogonal linear isomorphisms $\mathbb R^n\to T_xM$ (which is equivalent to the standard picture of oriented orthonormal frames via the image of the standard basis).